# What is the need for !< and !> operators in WHERE clause?

Tags: t-sql

Could any one please brief the need for the not less than (!<) and not greater than (!>) operators in T-SQL ? I know we can replace the use of this operator with >= and <= operators ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Presumably, it's to convey a clearer meaning when writing your statement.  Some people have trouble making the immediate mental switch from "Not less than" to "greater than or equal to" and vice versa.  They are logically equivalent, but sometimes the brain has difficulties with logic.  For people who better understand !> instead of <=, it makes sense to have the extra operators.

Answer (score 0):

Arguably, they are legacy. As well as [non-ISO as per MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188074.aspx)

Saying that, not less than can be used in day to day English too and the meaning may be clearer especially if expressed in a requirement in this fashion.

[Random news headline](http://economictimes.indiatimes.com/news/economy/indicators/Economy-to-grow-not-less-than-85-in-FY11FM/articleshow/6468163.cms): "Economy to grow not less than 8.5%"